# Nodejs Zoho API v2 "zcrmsdk" how to specify module in "configuration.properties" file for AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, oauth, aws-lambda, zoho

I'm using Zoho API V2 Nodejs package **"zcrmsdk"** and **AWS Lambda.**

According to **Zoho's** documentation for API v2 for nodejs : https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/developer/server-side-sdks/node-js.html

[Picture: Zoho Instructions for Token Storage Mechanism](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdcFL.png)

They instruct us we can specify our own custom module for **Token Storage Mechanism** by providing a module name in **configuration.properties => api.tokenmanagement**

However, I'm finding hard time to link the module name in **api.tokenmanagement**.

In my local environment, I did it successfully by specifying the path as: **api.tokenmanagement=../../../../resources/tokenmgmt.js**

(**tokenmgmt.js** is my custom token management module for Zoho)

However, I'm getting error "Cannot find module" while I deploy the project to **AWS Lamda**.

I'm not sure if I did not specify the module name (or/and path) correctly or it's the compatibility issue of **"zcrmsdk"** with **AWS Lamda**.

Nodejs package: **"zcrmsdk"** https://www.npmjs.com/package/zcrmsdk

Comment: I am facing the same issue and it is not working even in dev environment. did you resolved it?

Comment: @Sarathy you need to specify file location of **tokenmgmt.js** with respect to **configuration.properties** file [where your **api.tokenmanagement** is as a properties variable].